# Display posts from all custom post type taxanomies not regular categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set up a custom post type **(training)** and it has the taxanomy **(companies)**. I have assigned one post to the example taxanomy I have setup called **highwaysmedia**.

The following code is found on my **archive-training.php** page which is for this CPT. It's displaying categories from the regular post type though, and 1 post from each. I need it to display one post from each category/taxanomy of the custom post type '**training**'.

```
<?php
//for each category, show all posts
$cat_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'post_type' => 'training'
   );
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
      'showposts' => 1,
      'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
      if ($posts) {
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
          <?php
        } // foreach($posts
      } // if ($posts
    } // foreach($categories
?>
```

Here is the page I have this all set up on: http://www.highwaysindustry.com/training/

I am using the TYPES plugin for creating my custom post types.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can query for custom post type on taxonomies like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'training',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'companies',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'highwaysmedia'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```